# JPA Critera Query count results involving join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pagination, criteria-api

I'm using hibernate and the JPA criteria API and trying to create a re-usable utility method to determine how many rows a query will return.

Currently I have this:

```
Long countResults(CriteriaQuery cq, String alias){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root ent = countQuery.from(cq.getResultType());
    ent.alias(alias);
    countQuery.select(cb.count(ent));
    Predicate restriction = cq.getRestriction();
    if(restriction != null){
        countQuery.where(restriction);
    }
    return em().createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = cq.from(modelClass());
root.alias("ct");
cq.select(root);

TypedQuery<User> query = em().createQuery(cq);
long count = countResults(cq, "ct");
```

And that works fine.
However, when I use a more complicated query like

```
Join<UserThing, Thing> j = root.join(User_.things).join(UserThing_.thing);
cq.where(somePredicate);
```

My call to `countResults()` produces exceptions like `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'myAlias.name'`, `<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree`, `left-hand operand of a binary operator was null`

I'm guessing this has something to do with the join, and that I need to alias that somehow, but I've not had any success so far.

Help?

Comment: Have you looked at adding 'distinct' to your count?  Joins across collections create duplicates of the row values you are counting that Distinct would then filter.  You can call .distinct(true) on what you pass to count

Comment: @Chris gave that a try, didn't have any effect.

Comment: You are counting all the rows returned from your inner query.  instead of making it return the user, return only the distinct user ids.  Look at the SQL that gets generated and see what effect it has on your data.

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? Im having same issue!

Comment: @meobeo173 switched to jooq, haha. Hector has just added an answer though, give that a try and let us all know if it works.

Comment: Yeah i've solved by using QueryDSL, anyway switch to JOOQ is a greate idea, our product is overwhelmed under JPA.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I solved with:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countCriteria = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<EntityA> countRoot = countCriteria.from(cq.getResultType());
Set<Join<EntityA, ?>> joins = originalEntityRoot.getJoins();
for (Join<EntityA, ?> join :  joins) {
    countRoot.join(join.getAttribute().getName());
}
countCriteria.select(cb.count(countRoot));
if(finalPredicate != null)
    countCriteria.where(finalPredicate);

TypedQuery<Long> queryCount = entityManager.createQuery(countCriteria);
Long count = queryCount.getSingleResult();
```

Where

originalEntityRoot is the main root where I did the query with the where clauses.

Comment: This won't work if there's more than one layer of joins (i.e. joins on joins).